# JSDoc: Auto detecting class methods

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, docstring, jsdoc3

My jsdocs look like the following

```
module.exports = class gateio extends Exchange {
    /**
     * @class
     * @name gateio
     */

    async fetchOrder (id, symbol = undefined, params = {}) {
        /**
         * @method
         * @name gateio#fetchOrder
         * @description Retrieves information on an order
         * @param {string} id : Order id
         * @param {string} symbol : Unified market symbol
         * @param {boolean} params.stop : True if the order being fetched is a trigger order
         * @param {dictionary} params : Parameters specified by the exchange api
         * @returns [Order structure]{@link https://docs.ccxt.com/en/latest/manual.html#order-structure}
         */
```

Is there any way to auto detect that

- that `fetchOrder` is a method
- its name is `fetchOrder` and it belongs to class `gateio`
- its description is "Retrieves information on an order"
- That gateio is a class
- that gateio's name is gateio

Or do I have to specify @method, @name, @class, @description for every doc?

These @'s seem superfluous and I would like to exclude them if I could

Answer (score 0):

It seems like jsdoc is confused by `module.exports = class ...` .
I was able to get it to work like this:

```js
/**
 * (description text)
 */
class gateio extends Exchange {
    /**
     * Retrieves information on an order
     * @param {string} id : Order id
     * @param {string} symbol : Unified market symbol
     * @param {boolean} params.stop : True if the order being fetched is a trigger order
     * @param {dictionary} params : Parameters specified by the exchange api
     * @returns [Order structure]{@link https://docs.ccxt.com/en/latest/manual.html#order-structure}
     */
    async fetchOrder (id, symbol = undefined, params = {}) {
        // ...
    }
}
module.exports = gateio
```